# Java program to calculate directory size keeps throwing NPE

Tags: java, size, directory

I'm working on a program that loops through a specific directory (example, C:\Documents) and calculates the total size taken up by it on the disk. For some reason, however, my program keeps throwing a null pointer exception at a point where it seems to be looking for a folder called "My Music" within the Documents folder. "My Music" does not exist in my Documents folder, so I am very confused about where it gets it from. I understand why it's throwing the exception (obviously if it can't find the folder within the designated directory, it'll return null), but I have no idea how it finds "My Music" in the first place. Here is the code I have:

```
public static Long getDirSize(File directory) {
    long size = 0L;
    for (File file : directory.listFiles()) {
        size += file.isDirectory() ? getDirSize(file) : file.length();
    }
    return size;
}
```

And to call this method, I use the following:

```
long required = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < directories.length; i++){
required = required + getDirSize(new File(directories[i]));
```

"directories" is an array of strings containing the directories whose size I'm trying to calculate. For example, 
    directories = {"C:\Users\user\Documents", 
                   "C:\Users\user\Pictures", 
                   "C:\Users\user\Videos"}

I've been trying to solve this for several weeks, trying different methods to loop through the directories, etc and they all seem to give me the same problems. I would very much appreciate another set of eyes on this. Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the stacktrace--

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at diana.Review.getDirSize(Review.java:206)
at diana.Review.getDirSize(Review.java:207)
at diana.Review$2.actionPerformed(Review.java:126)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The code looks OK, can you post your stack trace?

Comment: Let me guess. You're on WIndows Viste or later? In that case, MyDocuments is a Junction (I think they still didn'T move to symlinks, although NTFS now supports them), and Java doesn't seem to be able to handle those on NTFS filesystems.

Comment: @user2310289 Stacktrace has been added.

Comment: @Johannes H, you're right--I'm on Windows 8.

Comment: @JohannesH., I have not heard the term "Junction" before in this context. What does it mean, in this case?

Comment: @derstrom8 : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point - basically a ugly way of implementing symlinks. As the latest NTFS now supports real symlinks, there is no (legitimate) use for Junction points anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listFiles() can return null. See the Javadoc. You need to test for that before you loop. That means you can't use the enhanced for-loop on it.

Comment: I think I attempted to do the check to make sure it wasn't null once, but ran into this very problem. How would you suggest I modify it to avoid the issue?

Comment: It seems to me I've answered that, unless you're asking to be spoonfed code.

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't my intention. I was trying to figure out how I would be able to loop through the directories without the enhanced for loop, in a way that would allow me to check whether or not listFiles() is null each time. It seems to me like that in itself would require the loop. I don't ask for code, I'm just trying to get pointed in the right direction

Comment: You don't have to check whether isFiles() returns null each time. You only have to check it once, *or* loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help EJP. I was thinking it had to be checked every time. I put a check right at the start of the method and it all seems to be working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would try testing the file before actually using it. I would do something similar to `if(file != null)` or `if(file.exists())`. This way if the file doesn't exist you don't try to use it. This should solve your problem of getting an error.

Also, with the way Windows works, in your My Documents directory there is by default a folder called "Music", but depending on where you access this from in, say, explorer it might say "My Music" or "User's Music". I wasn't ever sure why this happened, but for some reason it does.

So a basically foolproof way to stop getting this error is to just check to see if the file you're about to use exists. If it doesn't, just skip over it or print an error message. Hope this helps.

Comment: I can tell you why explorer lists different names: It's inside the hidden files called "desktop.ini". Ugly hack for proper localisation, confuses "power-users" that actually need to know how directories are aclled outside windows explorer and causes more trouble than it solves. First thing I do when having to deal with a windows system is deleting those entries.

Comment: Ah, so that's how that happens. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: The "Music" or "My Music" or "User Music" folder is directly in my C drive, completely separate from "Documents" (a.k.a. "My Documents"). It seems like when it finishes looping through the existing folders inside Documents, it backs out of the Documents directory and into the C directory, and looks at the next folder (My Music), but it still looks for it in the documents directory. I don't know if this makes any sense....