# For loop only executes twice when copying files

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, swingworker

I came across a very strange problem in my program I wrote to copy Pictures, Documents, Videos, and Music (from the Windows file system) to a backup drive. I set a string array `directories[]` equal to `{picturesDirectory, documentsDirectory, videosDirectory, musicDirectory}` and use a for loop to loop through each one to copy the files. I use a GUI so I have a SwingWorker that runs the actual copy methods. However, when I run the program, it only loops through the "for" loop twice, only copying pictures and documents. I don't think I can really post a SSCCE that will help, so I'm just posting my entire class. `inDrive` is the main Windows drive ("C" by default), `outDrive` is the backup drive letter, `username` is the windows username, and `space` is the total disk space that the files/directories will take up.

```
package diana;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BasicCopy extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel bottomPane;
    private JTextArea txtCopiedDirs;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private JButton btnCancel;
    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    private JLabel lblCopying;
    private JLabel lblProgress;
    private static String mainDrive;
    private static String backupDrive;
    private static String username;
    private static String backupDir;
    double totalSize = 0;    //total size of directories/files
    double currentMB = 0;    //size of already-copied files
    static double currentSize = 0;  //current size of files counting up to ONE_PERCENT
    static int currentPercent = 0;  //current progress in %
    static double ONE_PERCENT;  //totalSize / 100
    private ManipulateDirectories md;
    private Task task;

    public BasicCopy() {
    }

    public BasicCopy(String inDrive, String outDrive, String username, long space) {
        mainDrive = inDrive;
        backupDrive = outDrive;
        BasicCopy.username = username;
        totalSize = space;
        ONE_PERCENT = totalSize / 100;
        createGUI();
    }

    public void createGUI() {

        // Create frame
        setTitle("Backup Progress");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 500, 350);

        // Create panel for text area/scroll pane
        contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        // Create panel for progress bar/cancel button
        bottomPane = new JPanel();
        bottomPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        lblCopying = new JLabel("Now backing up your files....\n");
        lblCopying.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.add(lblCopying, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        // Create text area/scroll pane
        txtCopiedDirs = new JTextArea(10, 50);
        txtCopiedDirs.setEditable(false);
        DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) txtCopiedDirs.getCaret();
        caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(txtCopiedDirs);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        lblProgress = new JLabel("Progress:");

        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        progressBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

        btnCancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        btnCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup Cancelled!");
                closeWindow();
            }
        });

        bottomPane.add(lblProgress, Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        bottomPane.add(progressBar, Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        bottomPane.add(btnCancel, Component.RIGHT_ALIGNMENT);

        contentPane.add(bottomPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        PropertyChangeListener listener = new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
                if ("progress".equals(event.getPropertyName())) {
                    currentPercent = (int) event.getNewValue();
                    progressBar.setValue((int) currentPercent);
                    progressBar.setString(Integer.toString(currentPercent) + "% ("
                        + String.format("%.2f", (currentMB / 1048576))
                        + "MB of " + String.format("%.2f", (totalSize / 1048576)) + "MB)");
                }
            }
        };

        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        this.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - this.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - this.getSize().height / 2);
        setVisible(true);
        task = new Task();
        task.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        task.execute();
    }

    /**
     * Swing Worker class
     */
    class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, String> {

        public Task() {
            md = new ManipulateDirectories(this);
        }

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {
            md.makeBackupDirectory();

            // Directories to be copied
            String pics = mainDrive + ":\\Users\\" + username + "\\Pictures\\";
            String docs = mainDrive + ":\\Users\\" + username + "\\Documents\\";
            String vids = mainDrive + ":\\Users\\" + username + "\\Videos\\";
            String musc = mainDrive + ":\\Users\\" + username + "\\Music\\";

            File[] directories = { new File(pics), new File(docs), new File(vids), new File(musc) };

            /********** THIS ONLY LOOPS THROUGH PICS AND DOCS **********/
            for (int i = 0; i < directories.length; i++) {
                md.copyDirectory(directories[i], new File(backupDir));
            }
            /***********************************************************/
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void process(List<String> chunks) {
            for (String path : chunks) {
                txtCopiedDirs.append(path);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void done() {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Backup complete!");
            closeWindow();
        }

        public void updateProgress(int tick) {
            if (progressBar.isIndeterminate())
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressBar.setString(Integer.toString(currentPercent) + "% ("
                + String.format("%.2f", (currentMB / 1048576)) + "MB of "
                + String.format("%.2f", (totalSize / 1048576)) + "MB)");
        }

        public void publishText(String filename) {
            publish(filename + "\n");
        }
    }

    public class ManipulateDirectories {
        Task task;

        public ManipulateDirectories(Task task) {
            this.task = task;
        }

        public void makeBackupDirectory() {
            // Create Backup Directory
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_HHmmss");
            String timestamp = sdf.format(date);
            backupDir = backupDrive + ":\\" + "Backup_" + timestamp;
            File backupDirectory = new File(backupDir);
            backupDirectory.mkdir();
                task.updateProgress(0);
        }

        // Recursive function to loop through and copy individual files
        public void copyDirectory(File file, File dest) {
            if (file.isFile()) {
                try {
                    FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(file, dest);
                    currentMB = currentMB + getDirSize(file);
                    currentSize = currentSize + getDirSize(file);
                    if (currentSize >= ONE_PERCENT) {
                        currentPercent = currentPercent + (int) (currentSize / ONE_PERCENT);
                        currentSize = currentSize % ONE_PERCENT;
                    }
                    task.updateProgress(currentPercent);
                    task.publishText(file.getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                File newDir = new File(String.format("%s\\%s", dest.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName()));
                if (!newDir.exists()) {
                    newDir.mkdir();
                    for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
                        copyDirectory(f, newDir);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public Long getDirSize(File file) {
            long size = 0L;

            if (file.isFile() && file != null) {
                size += file.isDirectory() ? getDirSize(file) : file.length();
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
                    size += f.isDirectory() ? getDirSize(f) : file.length();
                }
            }
            return size;
        }
    }

    /* Close current window */
    public void closeWindow() {
        WindowEvent close = new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(close);
        System.exit(0);
   }
}
```

I added a comment around the for loop that is only being executed twice. I placed a breakpoint and it never gets there after copying documents, so it must call the SwingWorker's `done()` method before then.

Does anyone see what might cause this problem? I really hate posting all my code here, as I understand it's often a pain to read through it all. I'm hoping someone can find why it's ending prematurely though. Many thanks!

**EDIT:**

After further debugging (based on some of the suggestions from the comments), I have discovered there is a NPE due to the program looking for "My Music" within the Documents folder--a "link" that doesn't exist as a directory (hence the null value).

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker.get(Unknown Source)
at diana.BasicCopy$Task.done(BasicCopy.java:181)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$5.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at diana.BasicCopy$ManipulateDirectories.copyDirectory(BasicCopy.java:243)
at diana.BasicCopy$ManipulateDirectories.copyDirectory(BasicCopy.java:244)
at diana.BasicCopy$Task.doInBackground(BasicCopy.java:166)
at diana.BasicCopy$Task.doInBackground(BasicCopy.java:1)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I was under the impression I wouldn't have to worry about this since I use the file.isFile() and file.isDirectory() checks. According to the javadocs, these only return true if the file is a file/directory AND if it exists. I assumed (probably stupidly) that it should skip over anything like My Music since it doesn't exist as a directory?

Comment: Have you put a break point after your loop to make sure it actually is getting there and not just stopping the whole program? Is it possible that your code hits an error while copying documents, which is why it stops?

Comment: Is there a necessary reason that `Task` and `ManipulateDirectories` to be too coupled?

Comment: @Jordan, yes I have. I also have try/catch statements to make sure there's not an error in the copying methods. I placed a breakpoint inside the catch and it was never hit.

Comment: @nachokk, I had to create the ManipulateDirectories class so that I could use a recursive function to loop through the files. I'm thinking there was another reason I did it that way as well, but I can't seem to remember what it was. I'm not sure if this is answering your question, I didn't quite understand what you were asking

Comment: Well my comment is offtopic of your question but what i mean is that `Task` knows `ManipulateDirectories`, and `ManipulateDirectories` knows `Task`, what i mean is that `Task` lives cause  `ManipulateDirectories` lives and viceversa, and i don't think it's a good design

Comment: How do you know it only runs the first two? Did you place a breakpoint in `CopyDirectory`?

Comment: @nachokk, I see what you mean now. Yeah, it's not the best design, One relies on the other and vice versa. Right now I'm just trying to get the code to work, then I'll start optimizing it.

Comment: @JimGarrison, yes I did. I also placed a breakpoint inside the for loop, and it only hits that breakpoint twice. I have several breakpoints in CopyDirectory and it only copies the Pictures and Documents folders

Comment: When you hit the breakpoint in the loop, what is the value of `directories.length`?

Comment: remember that you are debugging in at least 2 threads

Comment: Override the done method of the SwingWorker and call get. You'll need to wrap it in a try-catch block, this will allow you to determine if there is an exception been thrown...

Comment: "get()" is giving me a NPE (it doesn't make it to "get", the try/catch surrounding it takes me to the catch, which is a NPE)

Comment: Locate the point in the code that generates the NPE

Comment: I am attempting to locate that point but cannot seem to find it. I will keep looking though

Comment: Post the NPE as part of the question

Comment: NPE and further information has been added. By the way, any particular reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the existing `java.io.File` API can't handle symbolic links (or what ever they call them in Windows). Directories like "My Music" aren't actually a File/directory in the traditional sense, but are a special marker pointing to another file/directory.

In order to overcome this, you'll need to take a look at the new [Paths/Files API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) available in Java 7

For more details, try taking a look at [Links, Symbolic or Otherwise](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html)

Comment: I am not using the symbolic links though, I am using the actual directories located inside the user directory. Does it still try to access the symbolic links even though I do this?

Comment: @derstrom8. "My Music" is not an "actual directory", as MadProgrammer is pointing out. Unfortunately, Microsoft made it a sym-link whether you like it or not.

Comment: I'm not at my PC, but from memory, they might be.

Comment: You guys are correct, it's searching for "My Music" (not an actual directory) within the Documents folder. I've had this issue before when working with batch scripts. IIRC I simply added in a line checking to see if the directory existed, and since "My Music" doesn't exist, it would skip right over it and continue working. However, I am using if (file.isFile()) and (file.isDirectory()) which, according to the Javadoc, should skip over it if the directory doesn't exist, so I'm not sure why it's still trying

Comment: +1 another good catch! better than yesterday ,in your country perhaps was 2 days ago hihi

Comment: @nachokk When I have a proper keyboard, I do all right, some times ;)

Comment: Just checking, before I accept this answer, trying to use listFiles() on a sym-link (or whatever they're called) will return a null, correct? If that's the case, then my work-around is still a solution, no? I'll still accept this one if it is in fact the root cause of the NPE, but the workaround still seems like a perfectly reasonable answer to me. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `File#listFiles` will return `null` if the abstract path that the `File` reference represents does not exist or is not a valid path, so, yes, in short, this is why you are getting a `NPE`, because as far as the `java.io.File` API is concerned, "...\My Music" does not represent a valid path as it knows it...

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It was the same problem I was asking about in this thread, and was thinking the solution was something else: [Java program to calculate directory size keeps throwing NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19968131/java-program-to-calculate-directory-size-keeps-throwing-npe)

The problem is that file.listFiles() was null when run while the file path was C:\Users\user\Documents\My Music. To fix it I simply put in an if statement to check that file.listFiles() != null before the "for" loop at the bottom of the copyDirectory method:

```
if (file.listFiles() != null){
    for (File f : file.listFiles()) {
        copyDirectory(f, newDir);
    }
}
```

I'm sorry for posting this here when apparently I already had the same problem that was answered in another thread. Hopefully this helps someone though. Thank you all for your suggestions, they are appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't "fix" the underlying problem of the fact the the `java.io.File` API can't handle symbolic links, it's a work around at best...

Comment: Yes, I agree. Thankfully a work-around is all I needed at this point. If necessary, in the future, I'll go ahead and look through the new API and make changes if necessary. But I'm not going to bother right now, since it's not terribly important. Thank you for your suggestions, they did eventually point me in the right direction